# Please wait screen appearing after the login button

Tags: blackberry, popup, progress, pleasewait

I am trying to implement a "Wait Screen" in my BlackBerry app. The screen is to appear when the user clicks "Login" and it should go away after login has successfully been made. I am calling the screen in the "Login" listener after which I call a methd to fetch data from webs ervice. When the data is fetched, and the new screen is shown, the "Wait Screen" should disappear. However, on clicking login I get `Uncaught - RuntimeException` after which new screen is displayed with the "Waiting Screen" on top of it. Can somebody help me with this?

```java
public class MessageScreen extends PopupScreen
{
    private String message;

    public MessageScreen (String message)
    {
        super( new HorizontalFieldManager(), Field.NON_FOCUSABLE);
        this.message = message;
        final BitmapField logo = new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "cycle.gif"));
        logo.setSpace( 5, 5 );
        add(logo);

        RichTextField rtf = new RichTextField(message, Field.FIELD_VCENTER | Field.NON_FOCUSABLE | Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
        rtf.setEditable( false );

        add(rtf);
    }
}
```

I am calling this in the "Login" click event - button listener.

```java
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context)
{
    // Push appropriate screen depending on which button was clicked
    String uname = username.getText();
    String pwd = passwd.getText();
    if (uname.length() == 0 || pwd.length()==0) {
        Dialog.alert("One of the textfield is empty!");
    } else {
        C0NNECTION_EXTENSION=checkInternetConnection();
        if(C0NNECTION_EXTENSION==null)
        {
            Dialog.alert("Check internet connection and try again");
        }
        else
        {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater( new Runnable()
            {
                public void run ()
                {
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen( new MessageScreen("Signing in...") );
                }
            } );
            doLogin(uname, pwd);
        }
    }
}

private String doLogin(String user_id, String password)
{
    String URL ="";
    String METHOD_NAME = "ValidateCredentials";
    String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE+METHOD_NAME;
    SoapObject resultRequestSOAP = null;
    HttpConnection httpConn = null;
    HttpTransport httpt;
    SoapPrimitive response = null;
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("username", user_id);
    request.addProperty("password", password);
    System.out.println("The request is=======" + request.toString());
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    httpt = new HttpTransport(URL+C0NNECTION_EXTENSION);
    httpt.debug = true;
    try
    {
        httpt.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        String result =  response.toString();
        resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        String[] listResult = split(result, sep);
        strResult = listResult[0].toString();
        strsessionFirstName = listResult[1].toString();
        strsessionLastName = listResult[2].toString();
        strsessionPictureUrl = MAINURL + listResult[3].substring(2);
        strsessionStatusId = listResult[4].toString();
        strsessionStatusMessage = listResult[5].toString();
        strsessionLastUpdateTst = listResult[6].toString();

        if(strResult.equals("credentialaccepted"))
        {
            if(checkBox1.getChecked() == true)
            {
                persistentHashtable.put("username", user_id);
                persistentHashtable.put("password", password);
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = getLiveImage(strsessionPictureUrl, 140, 140);
            StatusActivity nextScreen = new StatusActivity();
            nextScreen.getUsername(user_id);
            nextScreen.getPassword(password);
            nextScreen.setPictureUrl(bitmap);
            nextScreen.setImage(strsessionPictureUrl);
            nextScreen.setFirstName(strsessionFirstName, strsessionLastName, strsessionLastUpdateTst, strsessionStatusMessage);
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(nextScreen);
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater( new Runnable()
            {
                public void run ()
                {
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen( UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen() );
                }
            } );
        }
        if(strResult.equals("credentialdenied"))
        {
            Dialog.alert("Invalid login details.");
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new LoginTestScreen() );
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("The exception is IO==" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("The exception xml parser example==="
        + e.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println( resultRequestSOAP);
    //UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen( UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen() );
    return response + "";

    //UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new InfoScreen());
    //Open a new Screen
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Eugen said, you should run `doLogin()` on a background `Thread`:

```java
final String uname = username.getText();
final String pwd = passwd.getText();

Thread backgroundWorker = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        doLogin(uname, pwd);
    }
});

backgroundWorker.start();
```

If you do that, you'll need to use `UiApplication.invokeLater()` (or another similar technique) to show your screens (back on the main/UI thread).  You can't leave the `doLogin()` method exactly as it originally was, because it makes calls to change the UI.  For example, you have a couple calls to directly use `pushScreen()`, which should not be called (directly) from the background.

This is not ok (from the background):

```java
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(nextScreen);
```

But, this is:

```java
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            public void run ()
            {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(nextScreen);
            }
        } );
```

But, also, what is this code supposed to do? :

```java
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(nextScreen);
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            public void run ()
            {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen( UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen() );
            }
        } );
```

This doesn't make sense to me.  What are you trying to do with those lines of code?

Comment: with the above line of code " UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen( UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen() ); " I was trying to hide the "waiting screen" and make the new push screen as active. I tried implementing the method through the thread as you suggested but it throws an error NullPointerException

Comment: @Sarah, you don't use `pushScreen()` to **hide** screens.  You use it to **show** screens.  The line before that, you call `pushScreen(nextScreen)`.  That will show the `nextScreen`.  Is that what you want showing?  If so, then remove the next line, with the `Runnable`.  If you don't want `nextScreen` showing, don't push it.  **Where** do you get a `NullPointerException`?  Which line?  It doesn't really help us to say that `NullPointerException` is thrown.  Almost any line can cause that exception.  You need to run in the debugger, and find out **where** it's thrown.

Comment: I am aware about "pushScreen()" to show screen. What I was trying was with .getActiveScreen thinking to supress the wait message. I am debugging and will check the exact line where this is thrown.

Comment: I am getting an error UiEngineImpl.assertHaveEventLock(). I believe the thread is not being closed properly. In my "Login Button" I am doing: Thread backgroundWorker = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
               doLogin(uname, pwd);
           }
                });
Dialog busyDialog = new Dialog("Signing in...", null, null, 0, Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.HOURGLASS));
            busyDialog.setEscapeEnabled(false);
            synchronized (Application.getEventLock()) {
            busyDialog.show();
            }
         backgroundWorker.start();

Comment: In the doLogin() method, the erorr is thrown at the pushScreen. This is what the debugger is seen "UiEngineImpl.assertHaveEventLock()"

Comment: @Sarah, Right.  You didn't follow my recommendation.  Please read my answer again.  If you simply run `doLogin()` in the background, then anything inside the `doLogin()` method that attempts to change the UI has to be moved into a call that runs it on the UI thread.  One way to do that is to wrap the UI call with `UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { /* do UI stuff here */ });`

Comment: @Sarah, you're welcome.  Hang in there.  Threading with BlackBerry can be tough to get right, but once you do it a few times, and learn the basic rules, it'll be much easier!

Answer (score 2):

I see only one issue so far - networking in the UI thread. Please put all your networ operations into another `Thread.run()`.

You could also get more detailed error description by:
1) Navigate to home screen
2) Hold alt button and press LGLG on the keyboard
3) Explore showed event log for specific error

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context)
{
// Push appropriate screen depending on which button was clicked
String uname = username.getText();
String pwd = passwd.getText();
if (uname.length() == 0 || pwd.length()==0) {
    Dialog.alert("One of the textfield is empty!");
} else {
    C0NNECTION_EXTENSION=checkInternetConnection();
    if(C0NNECTION_EXTENSION==null)
    {
        Dialog.alert("Check internet connection and try again");
    }
    else
    {

    Dialog busyDialog = new Dialog("Signing in...", null, null, 0, Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.HOURGLASS));
    busyDialog.setEscapeEnabled(false);
    synchronized (Application.getEventLock()) {
    busyDialog.show();
    }
    doLogin(uname, pwd);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the example. However this is not working for me. The "Signing in..." pop never appears and instead of showing the new screen it throws NullPonterException

Comment: NullPonterException is because of missing any resources.